# Conditionals in .htaccess - testing env var using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to deny when two conditionals are set.

I have set the variable in my `apache2.conf`:

```
SetEnv MY_SITE stage
```

and then in `.htaccess` I am checking that the header and env variable match up.

```
# check the variable is set by outputting to header. 
RewriteCond %{ENV:MY_SITE} (.+)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MY_SITE:%1]
Header always set X-Site %{MY_SITE}e
```

And then deny access if the header is wrong and this is staging:

```
# check the azure header and that this is staging
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Azure-FDID} !^xxxxxx$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:MY_SITE} =stage
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

However the second conditional does not result in the forbidden message.

If I try this, it works and denys access:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Azure-FDID} !^xxxxxx$ [NC]
# RewriteCond %{ENV:MY_SITE} =stage
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

But this does not:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:MY_SITE} =stage
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Why does the second conditional not work?

Comment: Does it work if you modify your condition pattern like `RewriteCond %{ENV:MY_SITE} stage [NC]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> SetEnv MY_SITE stage
> ```

`SetEnv` (mod_env) is processed too late for mod_rewrite to pick it up (mod_rewrite is processed early). You need to use `SetEnvIf` (mod_setenvif) to set the env var instead, which is processed much earlier.

As noted in [the docs for `SetEnv`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv):

> The internal environment variables set by this directive are set after most early request processing directives are run, such as access control and URI-to-filename mapping. If the environment variable you're setting is meant as input into this early phase of processing such as the RewriteRule directive, you should instead set the environment variable with SetEnvIf.

[`SetEnvIf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) has a different syntax. To set this unconditionally, you would need to do something like the following instead:

```
SetEnvIf ^ ^ MY_SITE=stage
```

The first argument (`^`) is a regex that matches any request header. `^` is always successful.

The second argument (another `^`) is a regex that matches against the preceding argument value. Again, this is always successful.

When using env vars and mod_rewrite in a `.htaccess` context you need to be careful of any looping by the rewrite engine (eg. a standard front-controller pattern later in the `.htaccess` file could trigger this). If there is then on the second pass by the rewrite engine any env vars that are set during the first pass are renamed with a `REDIRECT_` prefix (eg. `REDIRECT_MY_SITE`). Third pass, `REDIRECT_REDIRECT_MY_SITE` etc. etc. So you may need to check for a `REDIRECT_<var>` instead or prevent additional passes by the rewrite engine. (mod_rewrite directives in a *server* or *virtualhost* context do not have this additional complexity by default.)

---

> ```
> # check the variable is set by outputting to header. 
> RewriteCond %{ENV:MY_SITE} (.+)
> RewriteRule ^ - [E=MY_SITE:%1]
> Header always set X-Site %{MY_SITE}e
> ```

In light of the above, this does not test what you think it does. In this case, the mod_rewrite rule does nothing (since `MY_SITE` is not set when this rule is processed). By the time `Header` is processed (which is processed very late), `SetEnv` has set the env var.

---

### Alternative using `Define`

> I have set the variable in my `apache2.conf`

However, since you have access to the server config then consider using a "defined" variable (using the [`Define` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#define)) instead of an environment variable. Variables cannot be *defined* in `.htaccess` (as they are set at compile time), but they can be tested for in `.htaccess` and are not "renamed" like env vars (as described above).

For example, in `apache2.conf`:

```
Define MY_SITE stage
```

In `.htaccess`:

```
<IfDefine MY_SITE>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Azure-FDID} !^xxxxxx$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [F]
</IfDefine>
```

This obviously does not actually check the value of `MY_SITE`, so it is assumed that it will only be set on the staging server (effectively a boolean). It would therefore be preferable to change the variable name to something like `STAGING_SITE` instead.

If `MY_SITE` could contain multiple values then you could check the value if you wish using the `${<varname>}` syntax. For example:

```
<IfDefine MY_SITE>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Azure-FDID} !^xxxxxx$ [NC]
    RewriteCond ${MY_SITE} =stage
    RewriteRule ^ - [F]
</IfDefine>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks.  I went for the define method as it seems clearer and easier.  working well.